# Google app Engine offset greater than 1000 in Full text search causing error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using GAE search API to perform text search , now the problem is that i can get maximum of 2000(with offset = 1000 and limit = 2000) results whereas my data is very large. So what should i do to get more than 2000 results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the search API and build full-text search indeces for your queries. My code for instance looks like this and searches an index:

```
def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime(1999,01,01))

        hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        # Sort up to  matching results by subject in descending order
        sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=ACCURACY)

        # Set query options
        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=50, cursor=cursor,
                sort_options=sort,
                number_found_accuracy=10000,
              #  returned_fields=['title', 'city', 'region','category', 'adID', 'date','price', 'type', 'company_ad', 'adID', 'cityID','regionID', 'hour','minute'],
             #snippeted_fields=['text']
              )
        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)
        logging.debug('query_string i find %s' , str(query.query_string))
        logging.debug('query_options i find %s' , str(query.options))
        # Execute the query
        return index.search(query)

    except search.PutError as e:
        logging.exception('caught PutError %s', e)

    except search.InternalError as e:
        logging.exception('caught InternalError %s', e)

    except search.DeleteError as e:
        logging.exception('caught DeleteError %s', e)

    except search.TransientError as e:
        logging.exception('caught TransientError %s', e)

    except search.InvalidRequest as e:
        logging.exception('caught InvalidError %s', e)

    except search.Error as e:
        logging.exception('caught unknown error  %s', e)

    return None
```

For pagination you can use cursors that can page large data sets. There's more info [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/).